# Android TileMode X OR Y only?

Tags: android

In my Activity's layout a have a background, which should be repeated by Y. There is no problem with repeating the background, when it is repeated on X and Y (just add `android:tileMode="repeat"`). Also, there is no problem with doing this above Android API 15:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_layout);

BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_repeating_bg);
bg.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);`
layout.setBackground(bg);
```

But the method `setBackground(<BitmapDrawable>)` is not available on Android API < 16.
What should I do when I want to repeat my background only by X or by Y in Android 2.3?
Thanks.
P.S. The background's width and height are both `MATCH_PARENT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I found the answer. I just need to check the version and use the appropriate method.

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)fragmentView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
    bg.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
    else
        layout.setBackground(bg);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make an xml file in the `drawable` folder (or any drawable folder really) that's in this format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/my_repeating_bg"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then do:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.name_of_xml_drawable);
```

If the width of the layout is set to `wrap_content`, only the Y will be tiled. If the height of the layout is set to `wrap_content`, only the X will be tiled.  Setting both to `match_parent` or `fill_parent` will tile both X and Y.

Comment: What if I want to stretch X'es so my background would cover all the screen and I want to repeat these stretched rows by Y?

Comment: You can't do that with tiles and backgrounds.  In this case, setting your `BitmapDrawable` to an `ImageView` that's in the background of your entire View.  You'll need to put it in a `RelativeLayout` or some other layout that allows overlapping.